# MySQL issue connecting to site with php

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, mamp

Every time I try to connect to my localhost (using MAMP), it tells me that either access was denied or that it can't connect!!! It is driving me crazy! I have the php example below. What am I missing, because apparently nobody on the web is having this same problem...

```
//setup db connection

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link, "iReport")
```

Comment: what is the error message being displayed ?

Comment: access denied = invalid username/password.

Comment: double check your username and password and permissions. Are you trying to write with your connection ? if so make sure you are not logging in as a read only user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try...

```
//Database Information

$dbhost = "serverip";
$dbname = "databasename";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "password";


//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: and telling the OP to switch to a deprecated library changes things.... how? Stuffing some parameters into variables is similarly useless.

Comment: this system follows a proper format keeping things more organized than the sample code above.

Comment: This got rid of my previous errors, but it brought one final one...do you have any idea what this means? You seem to have a great amount of experience...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(mywebsitehere)/lib.php on line 13

Comment: what is your code on line 13? I am guessing it is a quoting issue. (double quote inside of double quotes or just forgetting a quote mark...that kind of thing.. the key line for debugging is the on line 13)

Comment: line 13 is mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());, but I inserted my host, user, pass. I have also been getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(mywebsitehere)/lib.php on line 13.  Thanks for helping me out though user860869!

Comment: are all your variables saved in quotes ? so there is a " on each end of the variable content and thats it? as seen in my example. Also that "," at the end of your quoting of line 13, is that part of line 13? because if it is then that could be your issue

Comment: All i can say there is something wrong with your syntax, be is you forgot to close a line or a stray cama like i pointed in my previous comment.

Comment: can you post the variables and all like i did, omitting the important parts, exactly as you have it and use ` marks on both ends of the code to highlight it.

Comment: for the variables just delete the content and leave them blank..no fillers

Comment: And this is just specifically line 13:     mysql_connect ( $127.0.0.1, $(important), $business4)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());

Comment: thats the issue..."$127.0.0.1" use $dbhost..so replace "$127.0.0.1" with "$dbhost"...

Comment: actually all your variables... you need to use "$" then the variable name.. not its content..so once you fill in the variable information copy my code exactly below it... dont change a thing.. so the two lines of connecting and selecting the database should not be changed...they will be formed based on the variables you set

Comment: Thanks, but now it is telling me for line 13: Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server during query. I've got a decent connection on this side...so, I'm not exactly sure whats up. Again, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: NP,I will help with i can. This is my my method is better than what you had before, we now have a more detailed error. Are you sure that you have the database name correct. Also make sure the "//Database Information" is not on the same line as any of the variables as this might be commenting out some the the variables

Comment: Yup, they are on different lines. Stack flow just crumpled them. I also tried this on a remote server a minute ago. Same warning. It can't be my variables unless I am misunderstanding something

Comment: ok my suggestion is to post what you have now in a new question with your new error..this is something i have never seen before

Comment: Ok. Here is the link to a followup question with all of the information that I am doing in php scripts to connect with the MySQL database as well as the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702002/trying-to-get-mysql-to-connect-via-php-into-json-but-returning-errors-connectin