# Trying to get MySQL to connect via php into JSON, but returning errors connecting to MySQL from a php script

Tags: php, mysql, json, connection

Essentially, I am trying to print out information in JSON so that I can communicate with my app, but I cannot connect to the MySQL database from a php script for some odd reason. What could it be that causes the error: 
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(myphpwebsite)/lib.php on line 13
Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

Also, line 13 is indicating the line in lib.php:

`mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());`

It should also be noted that this is a followup to a previous question in case anyone wanted to track down the source: [MySQL issue connecting to site with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701358/mysql-issue-connecting-to-site-with-php).

Lastly, I get the same error from both a localhost and a remote server using mysql

lib.php

```
<?

//Database Information

$dbhost = "31.170.160.76";
$dbname = "testdatabase";
$dbuser = "(personalinformation)";
$dbpass = "tested123";


//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

//executes a given sql query with the params and returns an array as result
function query() {
    global $link;
    $debug = false;

    //get the sql query
    $args = func_get_args();
    $sql = array_shift($args);

    //secure the input
    for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
        $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
        $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
    }

    //build the final query
    $sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

    if ($debug) print $sql;

    //execute and fetch the results
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

        $rows = array();

        if ($result!==true)
        while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($rows,$d);
        }

        //return json
        return array('result'=>$rows);

    } else {

        //error
        return array('error'=>'Database error');
    }
}

//loads up the source image, resizes it and saves with -thumb in the file name
function thumb($srcFile, $sideInPx) {

  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcFile);
  $width = imagesx($image);
  $height = imagesy($image);

  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($sideInPx, $sideInPx);

  imagecopyresized($thumb,$image,0,0,0,0,$sideInPx,$sideInPx,$width,$height);

  imagejpeg($thumb, str_replace(".jpg","-thumb.jpg",$srcFile), 85);

  imagedestroy($thumb);
  imagedestroy($image);
}

?>
```

Index.php

```
<?
session_start();
require("lib.php");
require("api.php");

header("Content-Type: application/json");

switch ($_POST['command']) {
    case "login": 
        login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); break;

    case "register":
        register($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); break;

}

exit();
?>
```

api.php

```
<?php

function errorJson($msg){
    print json_encode(array('error'=>$msg));
    exit();
}

function register($user, $pass) {
    //check if username exists
    $login = query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='%s' limit 1", $user);
    if (count($login['result'])>0) {
        errorJson('Username already exists');

//try to register the user
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);
if (!$result['error']) {
    //success
    login($user, $pass);
} else {
    //error
    errorJson('Registration failed');
}
}
}
function login($user, $pass) {
    $result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

    if (count($result['result'])>0) {
        //authorized
        $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];
        print json_encode($result);
    } else {
        //not authorized
        errorJson('Authorization failed');
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: what is the error message being displayed ?

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /srv/disk11/1158855/www/(myphpwebsite)/lib.php on line 13 Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: It'd be helpful if you indicated WHICH of the many queries you're running actually triggers the error.

Comment: Did you google that error message? Lots of advice...

Comment: The error message is triggered by lib.php. And yes, I have googled it, but I believe that it is a specific instance for me. Not sure exactly what it could possibly be though...any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the matter. It turns out that my php code further down was conflicting with the login. That's why it wouldn't authenticate on multiple remote MySQL's and my own Localhost

Answer (score 0):

As this is on the "connect" line, the server has been found (otherwise you get a different message) but you've not negotiated your log in.

Straight from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-lost-connection.html):

> More rarely, it can happen when the client is attempting the initial connection to the server. In this case, if your connect_timeout value is set to only a few seconds, you may be able to resolve the problem by increasing it to ten seconds, perhaps more if you have a very long distance or slow connection.

If that isn't it, it's either a network problem or your connection has been terminated mid-authentication. Check that your mysql host doesn't have some weird validation that you're coming from a particualr IP (I say weird, as there are more standard ways of managing it than killing the authentication mid-flow), or try your PHP script from a a server that is closer to the MySQL server (closer in terms of network speed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I tried it on my local and on 2 remote servers...still the same error on all of them...

Comment: What did you set the timout to? And did you restart the MySQL server once the setting was changed?

Comment: set them to 10 seconds like you said (which should be more than enough) and I did restart all of them before trying...and the connection is fine on my end and the remote servers. Is there anything wrong with my code? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Nope - nothing wrong with the code. This happens on multiple SQL servers? Can you try connecting at the command line: "mysql -h 31.170.160.76 -u [username here] -p" as this lets me know that I'm not allowed to connect...